# Why the “dass” when comparing statements with “als dass”?

Tags: grammar, conjunction, comparison

From the Süddeutsche Zeitung:

> Mein Bruder interessiert sich eher nicht für die Frankfurter Buchmesse, die nächste Woche beginnt. Er liest lieber, als **dass** er anderen zuhören möchte, die über das Lesen reden oder schreiben.

Why is the *dass* necessary here? Two rough translations to English would be:

> He prefers reading over listening to others talking or writing about reading.
>   He rather likes to read than to listen to others talking or writing about reading.

I don’t really understand why this clause would need a *that* or *dass,* respectively.

Comment: "als dass" is correct German (http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/als_dass) but not used very often. You could instead write "Er liest lieber, als anderen zuzuhören, ...", which is also shorter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can only speculate about the origin of this grammatical feature but *als dass* is used if the *als* is comparitive (than) while only *als* is used if the *als* is temporal (when).

Some examples:

> Er stand lieber früh auf, als dass er arbeitslos war.
> He rather got up early than being unemployed (e.g., because he got a job that required him getting up early).
>
> Er stand lieber früh auf, als er arbeitslos war.
> He preferred getting up early (to getting up late) when he was unemployed (e.g., to keep his rhythm).
>
> Sie arbeitete lieber an der Lösung des Problems, als dass sie seine Ursachen erforschte.
> She preferred to work on the solution of the problem to investigating its causes.
>
> Sie arbeitete lieber an der Lösung des Problems, als sie seine Ursachen erforschte.
> She preferred to work on the solution of the problem, when she was investigating its causes.
> (E.g., she was charged to investigate the causes of the problem and did so but also worked on its solution, which she preferred to do.)

Note that it is more usual to use *zu* with an infinitive construct than *als dass,* e.g.:

> Er stand lieber früh auf, als arbeitslos zu sein.
>
> Sie arbeitete lieber an der Lösung des Problems, als seine Ursachen zu erforschen.

Answer (score 2):

One could write:

> Er liest lieber, als anderen zuzuhören, die ...

But as the sentence contains a *möchte*, and möchte is a subjunctive form which can't be converted to an infinitive, a complete clause has to be used, preceded by *dass* which introduces subordinate clauses.

> Er liest lieber, als dass er anderen zuhören möchte, die ...